# Почему не закрашивается иконка при клике на число?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Почему при клике на число иконка не закрашивается? При клике на иконку всё норм. Вроде прикрепил к ссылке, но не работает как нужно.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-content-target="#b-favorites-popover" title="" class="b-product-popover-trigger fav-link" data-original-title="">
   <span class="b-page-header__number">8</span>
   <i class="icon-favorites"></i>
</a>

$(function() {
    $('.fav-link').on('click', function(e) {
       $('.icon-favorites').toggleClass("active");
    });
    $(document).click(function (event) {
        if ($(event.target).closest('.icon-favorites').length == 0) {
           $('.icon-favorites').removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас происходит одновременно и добавление класса и удаление. При клике невозможно найти `closest`, потому что это сестринский элемент. Просто вместо `closest()` используйте метод `siblings()`

```
$(function() {
    $('.fav-link').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        $('.icon-favorites').toggleClass("active");
    });
    $(document).click(function (event) {
        console.log(event.target);
        console.log($(event.target).closest('.icon-favorites').length);
        if ($(event.target).siblings('.icon-favorites').length == 0) {
            $('.icon-favorites').removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Вариант хороший, но вот при клике на иконку она не закрашивается.

Comment: @drtvader а с чего бы ей закрашиваться?

Comment: тогда как сделать, что бы при клике на любой элемент в ссылке иконка закрашивалась?

Comment: @drtvader нет у вас никакой иконки, есть тег курсива `i`, примените к нему css-стили и тогда он закрасится.

Comment: иконка находится в теге курсива, в коде который я скинул, как раз при клике на иконку она закрашивается, в коде который скинули Вы при клике на иконку, она не закрашивается.

Comment: если закрашивалась в вашем коде, то в чем суть вопроса?)

Comment: объяснил неправильно) надо что бы при клике на любой элемент в в ссылке добавлялся класс active к элементу с классом icon-favorites. Мой код работает только при клике на элемент с классом icon-favorites, ваш метод работает только с элементом имеющим класс b-page-header__number. А как сделать, что бы со всеми работал.

Comment: у вас нет клика на icon-favorites, потому что он нулевой высоты и ширины в поданном примере.

Comment: $(document).click(function (event) {
        if ($(event.target).closest('.icon-favorites').length == 0) {
           $('.icon-favorites').removeClass('active');
        }
    });если вот этот кусок кода убираю, то при клике на любой элемент внутри ссылки класс active добавляется